# how to make an enemy walk from the side of the camera in uniy 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a topdown game in unity 2d about a fly that should dodge the **fly swatter**. The fly swatter comes from the side of the camera. And my question is how to make a fly swatter, I can't make it Collider 2d.
I am new to unity and want to make my first game
Forgive me if there are mistakes, I'm from the translator

I want to know how to make the fly swatter approach the background

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to dos this. I'm going to recommended the easy way

You can make a animation of the fly swatter and on each frame make the fly swatter bigger so it looks like its getting closer. there is a lot of videos on youtube saying how to do animations.

In regards to the code Unity has a lot of useful tools for animation and those videos can show you how to use them.

the actual hitbox for the fly swatter would be a bit more complicated as the hitbox should only be active for a set time (maybe when the animation of the fly swatter hits a table) for example, this can be set with code and tools in Unity.

Its been a longtime sense I worked in unity and im not sure how to write the code but I hope this explanation gives you some guidance. Also here are some videos.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/collision-section.html <- Unity Collision Manual

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oebtkjwjkcs <- Nice beginner animation tutorial for unity

Also make sure you look this stuff up before asking a question this only tock me a few minutes to find. :)